# Should I generate a new address per payment?

Tags: nodeos, eosjs

on the bitcoin network I generate a new address for each payment I am to receive.  this way I can associate the address with the sender and I can tell when the payment has been made by monitoring the address.  the payments all fall into my one wallet

on EOS there are accounts so payments to me would be made to my account.  how can I therefore tell when a payment has been made to me by a particular payee? can I read the transaction log somehow (using eosjs) and find the identity of the sending account there?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Yes, you can read the transaction log by sourcing the blockchain with tools like Demux or even trigger some actions on-chain by `apply`-ing your smart contract on messages to `eosio.token`.

I am quite not sure what you mean by making another "address", but for the second question, yes, it's possible.

1.If the subsequent actions after token transfer is executed on-block, you can set your contract to check for transactions to `eosio.token` which is the contract we interact when we transfer EOS system token.

EOSIO's action can be thought as interaction between message and its handler. Think of it as registering your contract to list of handlers of messages to `eosio.token`.
The way you achieve this by manipulating dispatcher, and in specific, the `apply` function.
I'll leave a simple sample code to help you catch a grasp.

```
void apply(int64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action) {
    if( (code == receiver && name{action} != "transfer"_n) || (name{code} == "eosio.token"_n && name{action} == "transfer"_n)) {
        switch( action ) {
// This transfer function is one implemented on your contract, not eosio.token, and will handle the actions you need.
            EOSIO_DISPATCH_HELPER( foo, (transfer) )
        }
    }
}
```

> DO NOT USE THIS CODE RIGHT AWAY! This code is simplified version without conditional statements to prevent malicious actions.

Playing around dispatcher is extremely dangerous so take your time on your own testnet before deploying it on the mainnet. This [link](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/writing-a-custom-dispatcher) might be helpful for you.

2.If the subsequent actions need to be done off-chain, consider using frameworks such as [`Demux`](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js). `Demux` is EOSIO official backend infrastructure built with javascript and is node-comaptible. When desired action happens, the action watcher you implemented will trigger action handlers which does the actual processing you need. Look at the [examples](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js/tree/develop/examples) code in github for more info.

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer but I'm not sure how it relates to my question.  perhaps as clarification: a customer needs to send me money for a specific use.  in bitcoin I create a fresh address for my wallet and he deposits funds.  I check the balances of the addresses I have handed out and when the right amount appears in the address I gave him, I know he paid.  how can I accomplish the same thing in EOS?

Comment: @ekkis By using custom dispatcher stated above, you can, for example, set your own contract to be triggered when someone transfers tokens to you. Perhaps then  you can place a table entry in your contract about how much token you have received and check whether it has reached a certain amount and can process whatever you offered the client.

Comment: Also, you can add some id value in the memo field of the transfer operation. For example in our marketplace you purchase by transfering EOS to our contract, with the memo {"inventoryId": 1} and our contract parses that, as described above.

Comment: @Jinu, the thing is I don't have a contract.  I have an account and I just want to be paid and know what I'm being paid for

Comment: @MartinWawrusch the info in the memo is a reasonable approach but it's riddled with issues because if the user forgets to include the info when they send the tokens or doesn't get the syntax just right, now it's a mess

Comment: @ekkis newer dapps abstract that away. The user never sees that part of the memo field. But yes, transfering to binance is always frightening. All because accounts cost money...

Comment: the thing is if you don't have a dapp in front but just a wallet, then you have to rely on the user to enter in something precisely, as is the case with hardware wallets

Comment: @ekkis I don't get the point of your comment right above. Even in case of Bitcoin, you would've had to provide front-interface to user for that certain per-account address. Even when that's not the case, there's no difference in forcing client to send tokens to certain address and to send tokens with certain memo filed.

Comment: @ekkis Plus, the memo part @Martin mentioned was just a complementary you can use for say, security purpose. Also, as stated in my answer, you can use `Demux` to track those transactions without DApps.

Comment: if a user is given an invoice, opens Scatter and send funds to my account, how do I know that those funds fullfil the invoice? the answer is: put the invoice number in the memo field.  but if the user puts in the wrong number it's a problem, or if he forgets to put in a value... in bitcoin this is not a problem because he's given an address to pay that is unique to that invoice.  that is the problem I'm trying to solve.  can I generate unique addresses for an EOS account in the same way I can do it in bitcoin, so that I don't have to rely on the user providing me with the invoice number?

Comment: @ekkis I think Martin and I answered your question good enough. We have explained how the requirements you need can be reached in EOSIO, but it seems like you need THAT specifically same method as in the BitCoin. You should think of EOSIO as a platform that lets you deploy own policy with flexibility using smart contracts instead of just a fast BitCoin. Why can't you just deploy contracts you need? P.S. I still don't get the reason why you are obsessed with the addresses, that is just another hard coded methodology BitCoin force you to follow.

Comment: it's not a question of my deploying my own smart contract.  that does not solve the problem.  and I'm not obsessed with the address.  that approach solves a problem that your suggestions do not, with the same degree of invulnerability.  adding metadata in the memo field is an ersatz solution that comes with the risks I already explained.  perhaps I should close this and ask a different question: is it possible to generate multiple addresses for an EOS account?